# lightning-combobox 'title' attribute removal

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to remove redundant title from options list inside lightning-combobox, either I cant penetrate deeply inside or Im doing something wrong. well initially it is not in the DOM unless I open it.

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/combobox/ it is that title here

docu

```
...
<span class="slds-truncate" title="Accounts">Accounts</span>
...
```

my html

```
<lightning-combobox name="numbers" variant="label-hidden"
      value={value} options={options} onchange={handleChange}>
</lightning-combobox>
```

my js

```
  removeTitle() {
    let titleSelector = ".slds-listbox__option .slds-media__body .slds-truncate"

    this.template.querySelectorAll(titleSelector).forEach(element => {
      element.removeAttribute("title");
    });
  }
```

I have tried different selector variations, I am running it inside renderedCallback(), I have tried running it inside onchange function but to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a feature of LWC's [Shadow DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_dom), which ensures both CSS and Element isolation.
You're allowed to modify only what is defined in your component. `<span class="slds-truncate" title="Accounts">Accounts</span>` is defined inside the `lightning-combobox` component, so your component is not aware of it, that's why `this.template.querySelectorAll(selector)` returns an empty list.

You could create your own combobox component from the blueprint you've linked in order to have that `title` attribute removed.

Comment: thank you RubenDG. helped.